# Form to Form Communication

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

My 1st **Form = Main** and my 2nd **Form = ChampionSelect**. I open ChampSelect from Main with This

```
private void pictureBox_championSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChampionSelect champSlct = new ChampionSelect();
    champSlct.Show();
}
```

And it opens showing 12 icons as picture boxes.

Now Based off what icon the person clicks

I want it to change the Image of `pictureBox_championSelect` on **Main** to the Image of the clicked Icon on **ChampionSelect**.

***For Ex:*** If you click on Ace's icon in **ChampionSelect** it should change  `pictureBox_championSelect` Image on **Main** to Ace.png which I have imported into Resources.

So I tried this

```
public partial class ChampionSelect : Form
{
    public ChampionSelect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.champSlct = Main;
    }

    Main champSlct;


    public void icon_slctAce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        champSlct.pictureBox_championSelect.Image = Properties.Resources.Ace;

    }
```

Which I learned from another post on here but, it says "Main is a 'Type' but used like a variable" and doesn't work. Eventually I will be changing other things based on which icon is clicked but i assume it will be similar to this so a point in the right direction will be more then helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an event in your ChampionSelect form and an handler which changes images in Main:

```
public partial class ChampionSelect : Form {
    public class ChampionSelectedEventArgs: EventArgs {
        public Image ChampionImage { get; set; }

        public ChampionSelectedEventArgs(Image championImage) {
            this.ChampionImage = championImage;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ChampionSelectedEventArgs> ChampionSelected;

    public ChampionSelect() { }

    protected void onChampionSelected(Image im) {
        if(this.ChampionSelected != null)
            this.ChampionSelected(this, new ChampionSelectedEventArgs(im));
    }

    public void icon_slctAce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        onChampionSelected(Properties.Resources.Ace);
    }
}

public partial class Main : Form {
    private void pictureBox_championSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ChampionSelect champSlct = new ChampionSelect());
        champSlct.ChampionSelected += this.championSelected;

        champSlct.Show();
    }

    private void championSelected(object sender, ChampionSelectedEventArgs e) {
        this.pictureBox_championSelect.Image = e.ChampionImage;
    }
}
```

Passing a whole form to ChampionSelect is kind of bad practice since you should provide components the minimum required information to achieve their goals. In this case, ChampionSelect doesn't need to access directly Main's pictureBox as this could cause great headaches later on in the developement (consider what happens if you decided you don't want a picturebox anymore or you want to do something more complicated).

Comment: That just confuses me even more.

Comment: @Marzdor Happens, especially at the first times ;) I have just created an event, pretty much like Click on buttons and pictureboxes. An event is nothing more than a custom function (in this case, Main.championSelected) which gets called when necessary (in this case, then a champion has been selected)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public partial class ChampionSelect : Form
{
    Main champSlct;

    public ChampionSelect(Main main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.champSlct = main;
    }

    public void icon_slctAce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        champSlct.ChampionSelect = Properties.Resources.Ace;
    }
}

public partial class ChampionSelect : Form
{
    public Image ChampionSelect
    {
        get { return pictureBox_championSelect.Image; }
        set { pictureBox_championSelect.Image = value; }
    }

    private void pictureBox_championSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var champSlct = new ChampionSelect(this))
        {
            champSlct.Show();
        }       
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Other solution could be that your ChampionSelect could have a public event whish is fired when a champion is selected and your Main form can subscribe on this. In the event argument you can pass the Image.